Cockroach aliens are changing people to survive an asteroid
I am trying to remember the name of a tv show where the main character is some sort of law enforcement or Govt. investigator trying to stop aliens (who can control and maybe were cockroaches) from changing people into cockroach like creatures to survive a coming asteroid impact. Live action and possibly on the scifi channel. It was in color and set in the US. It was in English.

Can you give rough dates of when you saw it, or when you think it might have been released?

I think it may have been between 2004-2009 but I'm not sure. Somewhere in that range.

Also in one episode (I think) the main characters had a device that used sound to hurt the creatures. For the creatures think something similar to Edgar from Men in Black but less jerky.

Is it an animated show or not?

No, it was a live action show.

I'm pretty sure what your describing is The Threshold TV show.
During the Show you don't see a clear image of the alien but it looks kinda cockroachy and In 1 episode they use sound on the people effected by the aliens. 

Oh my god yes. Thank you so much. It's been bugging me for days. This is the show.
